# Dynamically change layout from internet in android without updating apk

Tags: android, layout

If anyone is aware, Google often updates the Google Play Store app without actually pushing any update, like changing the shade of the top green colour. This is obvious because clearing data of the Google Play Store app, reverts the colour and some layouts to older format.

Also similarly for Google Chrome, when rectangular edges were changed to rounded edges, there was no update.

My question is how to get that behaviour? I have not been able to find how do that. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is firebase remote config it does exactly what you want

[Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) is a cloud service that lets you change the behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to download an app update.

here is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/)

Answer (score 1):

As somebody pointed out, you can use [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/). It is probably the best solution for your case.

If for some reason you don't want to do that (not using google's services, ...), and you application is connecting to your server, you can serve colors via API and save those colors in shared preferences on application startup, then just set colors from preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Last year I needed similar solution but with device targeting, resource caching, event listeners, etc. so I started open source project [Dynamico](https://github.com/jelic98/dynamico) which supports these and many other functionalities. Hope you'll find it useful!